# Database design: Multiple tables per user

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I'm attempting to build a database that stores messages for multiple users. Each user will be able to send/receive 5 different message "types" (strictly a label, actual data types will be the same). My initial thought was to create multiple tables for each user, representing the 5 different message types. I quickly learned this is not such a good idea. My next thought was to create 1 table per message type with a users column, but I'm not sure that's the best method either from a performance perspective. What happens if user 1 sends 100 message type 1's, while user 3 only sends 10? The remaining fields would be null values, and I'm really not sure if that makes a difference or not. Thoughts? Suggestions and/or suggested reading? Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that (the idea given in the subject of this question) will be tremendously inefficient. You'll need to introduce a new table each time a new user is created, and querying all them at once would be a nightmare.

It's far easier to be done with a *single* table for storing information about message. Each row in this table will correspond to one - and only - message.

Besides, this table should probably have three 'referential' columns: two for linking a specific message to its sender and receiver, and one for storing its type, that can be assigned only a limited set of values.

For example:

```
MSG_ID | SENDER_ID | RECEIVER_ID | MSG_TYPE | MSG_TEXT 
------------------------------------------------------
   1   |     1     |     2       |    1     | .......
   2   |     2     |     1       |    1     | #######
   3   |     1     |     3       |    2     | $$$$$$$
   4   |     3     |     1       |    2     | %%%%%%%

...
```

It'll be quite easy to get both all the messages sent *by* someone (with `WHERE sender_id = %someone_id%` clause), sent *to* someone (`WHERE receiver_id = %someone_id%`), of some specific type (`WHERE msg_type = %some_type%`). But what's best of it, one can easily combine these clauses to set up more sophisticated filters.

---

What you initially thought of, it seems, looks like this:

```
IS_MSG_TYPE1 | IS_MSG_TYPE2 | IS_MSG_TYPE3 | IS_MSG_TYPE4
---------------------------------------------------------
     1       |      0       |      0       |      0   
     0       |      1       |      0       |      0
     0       |      0       |      1       |      0
```

It can be `NULL`s instead of `0`, the core is still the same. And it's broken. Yes, you can still get all the messages of a single type with `WHERE is_msg_type_1 = 1` clause. But even such an easy task as getting a type of specific message becomes, well, not so easy: you'll have to check *each* of these 5 columns until you find the one that has `truthy` value.

The similar difficulties expect the one who tries to count the number of messages of each types (which is almost trivial with the structure given above: `COUNT(msg_id)... GROUP BY msg_type`.

So please, don't do this. ) Unless you have a very strong reason not to, try to structure your tables so that with the time passing by they will grow in height - not in width.

Comment: Perfect. I now have a better understanding of not only the what, but the why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The remaining fields would be null values

Except if you're designing your database vertically, there will be no remaining fields.

```
user   int
msgid  int
msg    text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table `tv_ge_main`.`Users`( 
   `USER_ID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `USER_NAME` varchar(128), 
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 )

create table `tv_ge_main`.`Message_Types`( 
   `MESSAGE_TYPE_ID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `MESSAGE_TYPE` varchar(128), 
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 )

create table `tv_ge_main`.`Messages`( 
   `MESSAGE_ID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `USER_ID` bigint , 
   `MESSAGE_TYPE_ID` bigint , 
   `MESSAGE_TEXT` varchar(255) , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 )
```